# AngularJS custom tags have height of auto

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

It always seems like when I am trying to style a directive I have a really hard time, because the directive will get a height of auto, which means that its contents don't work well with percentage heights. Sometimes it works to give the directive a height of 100% in CSS, often it doesn't. It seems like the hardest one is when the directive is in a div with display:table-cell.

Is there a reference anywhere that explains how this works in different browsers and what the best way to handle this cross-browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity, an unregistered custom tag such as what we have in Angular 1.x is an `HTMLUnknownElement`. As such, it doesn't have a `display` setting, so most browsers will default to "inline." [Once you know](https://www.impressivewebs.com/default-css-display-values-html-elements/), the answer is obvious: give the tag a `display:block` in CSS.